# function while loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to get this function to work properly in javascript, well it is working properly what i can get to happen is the bottom 
console.log (work(" gallons of water has been extracted from the carpet."));
I can't get the " gallons of water has been extracted from the carpet." to show up in that same line of code.

```
// Global variable
var waterGallons = 40

var work = function(total) {
    var water = 0;
    while (water < waterGallons) {
        console.log("The carpet company was called out to extract " + water + " gallons of water.")
        water+=4;
    };
    return waterGallons;
}

console.log (work(" gallons of water has been extracted from the carpet."));
```

So using the answers that i got for help with is what i came out with because i need to use a global variable. so my story will change by changing the global variable.

```
var total = 40

var work = function(total) {
    var water = 0;
    while (water < total) {
        console.log("The carpet company was called out to extract " + water + " gallons of water.")
        water+=4;
    };
    return water;
}

console.log (work(total) + " gallons of water has been extracted from the carpet.");
```

Id like to thank you guys again. I still have a boolean function, a array using a for loop function, and a procedure left. So using this i should be able to understand how to create the next parts of my assignment.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this method? It is unclear what exactly you are trying to make it do, considering it returns a global variable that is defined outside of the function.

Comment: And your argument `total` was not even used.

Comment: its school work, I'm trying to tell a story, this part of my story. I need to follow this flow chart. In this particular part i need to have a number argument-> number function -> local variables -> while loop true -> math -> output -> back to while loop, or false off while loop -> return number. I'm just learning about functions and I'm pretty sure i don't know what I'm doing... :/

Comment: Thank you lwburk and biril for your answers i think this helps out a lot for understanding how creating a function and argument, then calling the argument after "some code is ran"

Answer (score 1):

The argument to the function `work` corresponds to the formal parameter `total`, which is never printed or otherwise used. If you want to print it to the console, then, well, you have to print it to the console.

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but this is one possibility:

```
var waterGallons = 40;
var work = function() {
    var water = 0;
    while (water < waterGallons) {
        console.log("The carpet company was called out to extract " + 
                     water + " gallons of water.")
        water += 4;
    };
    return water;
}

console.log(work() + " gallons of water has been extracted from the carpet.");
```

If you *really do* want to pass the string as an argument to `work` and write it to the console *inside* that function, then use `console.log(total)`. Just remember to keep the `total` parameter that I removed in my example.

Answer (score 0):

And another version (guess) based on lwburk 's previous answer:

```
var work = function(total) {
    var water = 0;
    while (water < total) {
        console.log("The carpet company was called out to extract " + 
                     water + " gallons of water.")
        water += 4;
    };
    return water;
}

console.log (work(40) + " gallons of water has been extracted from the carpet.");
```

This will allow the callee to define the total gallons of water that should be extracted, using the 'total' argument.